# A MYSQL equivalence for SQL server sp_blitz

Tags: mysql

I took a look at Brent Ozar's sp_blitz and my attention was drawn to the numerous discoveries I can see at glance regarding the status of my Microsoft SQL server instance. Any idea on the existence of a similar open source code for MySQL database servers?

Comment: At least give us some clues about what that blitz does.  Maybe sample output.  Maybe the types of "status" you like from it.  There are many such products for MySQL, but many fail to provide _useful_ information.

Comment: This is a common health and stored procedure that flags the health and performance issues in a SQL server instance. Specific components I like about it include flagging databases that have not been backed up, processes intensively using the CPU, tables that do not have query store enabled, disabled indexes. So, I am curious to see if there is an alternative for MySQL.

Comment: I especially like the built-in [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) .  It gets you started figuring out what to do about performance problems.